# rails form_for url: posts_path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was following this tutorial for rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and I had got to the part in 5.2 where you change the line

```
<%= form_for :post do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
```

Every time I change it, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError in Posts#new

Showing /home/hiram/rails/blog/app/views/posts/new.html.erb where line #2 raised:

compile error
/home/hiram/rails/blog/app/views/posts/new.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
....append=  form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| @output_buf...
                              ^
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <h1>New Post</h1>
2: <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
3:  <p>
4:    <%= f.label :title %><br>
5:    <%= f.text_field :title %>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/new.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/hiram/rails/blog
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `url: posts_path` is Ruby 1.9 syntax. If you're getting that error, then you must be using Ruby 1.8.

You'll have to use the `:url => posts_path` syntax for Ruby 1.8:

```
<%= form_for :post, :url => posts_path do |f| %>
```

You can read more about Ruby hash syntax [here](http://breakthebit.org/post/8453341914/ruby-1-9-and-the-new-hash-syntax) and [here](http://logicalfriday.com/2011/06/20/i-dont-like-the-ruby-1-9-hash-syntax/).

I should note that Ruby 1.8 is no longer supported, so you should probably update to Ruby 1.9. If you do update, you can use either `url: posts_path` or `:url => posts_path` syntax - Ruby 1.9 understands them both.